# What are my chances of being allowed to enter UK as a visitor for the second time in one year?

Tags: visas

I carry a passport that needs not application - ie embankment.

I arrived at the end of 2016, was stamped six months and stayed one month only. For my previous visit, in 2012, I received permission to remain for one month and stayed less than that.

Assuming the permission to remain period expires when I leave the country, what are my chances of being allowed to visit for a further three months, or even six months, when next I apply for entry to UK?

I know, if asked at the border, I will need to provide proof of sufficient funds and of reasons for visiting. I have these.

Is there any point in trying to travel before the six months are over or is it definitely a new assessment?

Will the one month stay will be in my favour on my next visit?

I do not fully understand the subsequent visits issues.

Is it for the total?

Discretion of officer in charge.

I will need a minimum of two months.

For those who carry the same nationality of passport as I do there are always two or three people taken for further questioning, at least every flight I was on.

Comment: Oh my! Where are you coming from that has such a high rate of detention? What's your nationality.  Oh dear, please edit your question so we can think about a quality answer. Oh my!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you've been granted a UK visa before and your visit was entirely within the bounds of that visa, not even going so far as to stay the maximum allowed time*,  then this will count for a lot of points towards being accepted again with little trouble.

Basically the immigration authorities want proof you'll behave and go home when you're meant to.  Having already done this 2 out of 2 times is a good precedent.

*this does cause alarm bells.  Staying a day short of 6 months on a 6 month visa,  though technically legal,  would put the immigration authorities on alert.  In your case of staying just a month though it's a positive.